# Get text of a tag and the text of child tags

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy, tags, axes

I have this HTML

```html
<p>
        <strong>aquiline</strong>
        <i> adj. </i>
        of or like the eagle.
</p>
```

All this this node is wrapped by a `div` with `class= field-item even`

I would like to recive `Aquiline adj. of or like the eagle...`. Now i have this uncorrect xpath `response.xpath('//div[@class="field-item even"]//descendant-or-self::p/text()').getall()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is almost correct. Replace `p` with `*` to select all text nodes and not only text nodes of paragraph tags. Also using `normalize-space` function you can get all the text as one string instead of a list. See below code snippet.

```py
response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="field-item even"]//descendant-or-self::*)').get()
```